# Django and Nginx - Invalid HTTP_HOST header

Tags: django, nginx

I'm struggling to find out whats wrong with my Nginx config that is allowing this to happen. I believe it has something to do with me trying to force "www." in front of the domain name. I have the code for it to deny the illegal host headers that i've found in previous forums.

heres my current config file for nginx:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=allsite:10m rate=1r/s;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name _;

    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name www.example.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media/  {
        alias /home/django/myproject/static/media/;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/django/myproject/static/static-only/;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /home/django/myproject/static/static-only/img/favicon.ico;
    }

    ## Deny illegal Host headers
    if ($host !~* ^(example.com|www.example.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }

    location / {
        # apply rate limiting
        limit_req zone=allsite burst=15 nodelay;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Error coming from django:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.baidu.com:443'. You may need to add u'www.baidu.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Request repr():
<WSGIRequest
path:/www.baidu.com:443,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'HTTP_HOST': 'www.baidu.com:443',
 'HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION': 'Keep-Alive',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)',
 'PATH_INFO': u'www.baidu.com:443',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'RAW_URI': 'www.baidu.com:443',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '33284',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'CONNECT',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'www.baidu.com',
 'SERVER_PORT': '443',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/17.5',
 'gunicorn.socket': <socket at 0x7f757983b450 fileno=16 sock=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:9000 peer=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx>,
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7f75850bb1e0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper at 0x7f7580505c80>,
 'wsgi.input': <newrelic.api.web_transaction._WSGIInputWrapper object at 0x7f75736af490>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

Django Settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.xxx.xx.xxx', 'www.example.com', 'example.com']
```

xxx.xx... is the IP of the server, my domain is properly in there, its not actually example.com

Comment: Where do you see "Invalid HTTP_HOST header"? Can you give the exact details of the error and what you did to generate it together with access and error log entries.

Comment: added the error in the original post that I am getting from django.

Comment: paste your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` from settiings.py

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.xxx.xx.xxx', 'www.example.com', 'example.com'], xxx.xx... is the IP of the server, my domain is properly in there, its not actually example.com